# AVPlayer flashing when using replaceCurrentItem() - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem, avplayerlayer

I'm setting up an `AVPlayer` in a `UIView` in this way:

```
fileprivate func setUpAVPlayer(){
    
    self.cardModel?.urlStrings?.forEach({ (urlString) in
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: nil)
        playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
        self.playerItemArray.append(playerItem)
    })
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItemArray[0])
}
```

In `layoutSubviews` I lay out the playerLayer that displays the player:

```
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
self.playerView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)
playerLayer.frame = playerView.bounds
```

Upon a certain event I change the current item of the player:

```
fileprivate func goToNextVideo(){
    counter = counter+1
    counter = min(playerItemArray.count-1, counter)
    
    self.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: self.playerItemArray[self.counter])
    self.player?.seek(to: .zero)
    self.player?.play()
}
```

When I change the item the transition is not smooth and I can see a flash displaying the `view` **below**. There are some things I don't understand:

1. Why If I preloaded all the `AVPlayerItems` at the beginning (when I loop all urls strings) I still have to wait for them to be loaded when they become the `currentItem` of the AVPlayer?
2. For what concern the flickering effect I searched online and didn't find a solution, so I meticulously inspected the behaviour of the `AVPlayer` whenever changing Item and I describe it in this way:

**First** It shows a white view (view below)

**Second** It shows a frame of the video it is going to display (more of less the timeframe is at half of video)

**Third** It actually displays the video

This behaviour is really annoying and I'm wondering how I can solve it.

Comment: same problem here...

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit
import GPUImage
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var movie: GPUImageMovie = {
        let movie = GPUImageMovie()
        movie.yuvConversionSetup()
        movie.addTarget(imageView)
        return movie
    }()
    
    lazy var imageView: GPUImageView = {
        let view = GPUImageView()
        view.setBackgroundColorRed(1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var player: AVPlayer = {
        let player = AVPlayer()
        return player
    }()
    
    lazy var videoURLs: [URL] = {
        return [
            resource(filename: "video0.mp4"),
            resource(filename: "video1.mp4"),
            resource(filename: "video2.mp4"),
            resource(filename: "video3.mp4"),
        ].compactMap({ $0 })
    }()
    
    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("replaceCurrentItem", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    var index = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(button)
        imageView.frame = view.bounds
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.bounds.maxY - 100, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44)
    }

    func resource(filename: String) -> URL? {
        return Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func action(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let url = getVideoURL() {
            player.pause()
            movie.endProcessing()
            movie.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
            player.replaceCurrentItem(with: movie.playerItem)
            player.play()
            movie.startProcessing()
        }
    }
    
    func getVideoURL() -> URL? {
        if videoURLs.indices.contains(index) {
            let url = videoURLs[index]
            index = (index + 1) % videoURLs.count
            return url
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
}
```

The Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'Test' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'GPUImage'
end
```

When you call `replaceCurrentItem`, it will clean the image buffer then wait to render the next frame. So, the key point is to keep the last frame on the screen: Instead of using `AVPlayerLayer` to render video frame, you can use `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` to get the frame and render it using OpenGL ES (or Metal). You can also decide when to clean the image buffer.